# EntityManager JPA 1.0 LockModeType Behaviour

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, locking

I am using the following Statement in my code.

entityManager.lock(employee, LockModeType.WRITE);

I am using JPA 1.0 and also using EJB 3.0 Stateless Session Bean for managing transaction, also using SQL Server as database.

Currently I don't have any version column in my entity named Entity.

Do we need to release the lock explicitly after transaction completion or EJB already takes care of this?

Answer (score 0):

java EE 6 has [LockModeType.NONE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html#NONE)(JPA 2 has it) which you can release lock manually: `em.lock(obj, LockModeType.NONE)`

I think transaction commit should release all locks that are acquired for the objects that are committed. EJB does not do anything over there, all goes to jpa and it's impl.

Check [this](http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.com/2012/01/jpa-locking-mechanisms-in-jpa-2.html) as well